# How to run a shell script using cron and at

Tags: cron

I was trying to learn about crontab. I tried to execute shell script using crontab. But I did not get the expected result.
When I use crontab,

```
38 17 * * * bin/sh sh /home/agalya/unix/digiclock.sh
```

I can't execute the shell script.

when I use 'at' command also I did not get the output.I have a doubt whether I have given the path of shell script correctly.How should I give the path?

```
~$ at 17:25
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> /bin/sh sh /unix/digiclock.sh
at> <EOT>
job 9 at Sat Feb 20 17:25:00 2016
```

I am sure that the file has executable permission.

Comment: In your crontab entry, `bin/sh sh` doesn't make any sense. Either use `/bin/sh` (note leading slash) or just `sh` (if it's in the standard `PATH`), not both.

Comment: In fact, if the script itself is executable and contains a `#!`-line at the top, neither of `/bin/sh` and `sh` should be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your crontab entry contains stuff that must be removed. It should be

```
38 17 * * *  /home/agalya/unix/digiclock.sh
```

for an user crontab. If it's in `/etc/crontab` (system-wide crontab), then it must include the user that runs the command:

```
38 17 * * *  agalya  /home/agalya/unix/digiclock.sh
```

Comment: I have tried the above command but the shell script is not executing on the given time,Do I need to make any other changes??

Comment: 1) Have you tried to run the script to see if it works? 2) Check `/etc/cron.allow`and `/etc/cron.deny` to ensure that user agalya is allowed to use crontab.

Comment: I can run the script in command prompt.If I use write command in crontab it is working.How can I check whether agalya is allowed to use crontab.kindly give me a detailed explanation on how to check whether I am allowed to use crontab

Comment: `man crontab` will give you all the information you need.